# Convertir un JSON a un array

Tags: java, json, gson

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Cómo puedo convertir el objeto `result` a una lista (array) en *Java*?.

El *JSON* es algo como lo siguiente:

```
{
    "order_id": "12345",

    "paging": {
        "total": 41,
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 50
    },
    "results": [{
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Item Title1",
            "price": 330,
            "available_quantity": 1,
            "sold_quantity": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Item Title 2",
            "price": 310,
            "available_quantity": 1,
            "sold_quantity": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Hasta el momento intenté analizarlo con la clase `Search` (que contiene una lista de elementos con mismos atributos que los del *JSON*):

```
arrayreq = gson.fromJson(response.getResponseBody(), Search.class);
```

Y tambien intente esto:

```
arrayreq = gson.fromJson(response.getResponseBody(), String[].class);
```

Tengo 2 acciones similares funcionando pero ninguno de los *JSON* que parsean tiene listas.

Mi clase `Search.java`:

```
public class Search {
    private String order_id;
    private Paging paging;
    private List<Item> results;//No se si esta bien
```

Answer (score 2):

Te refieres al objeto Results no?

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(cadenaJSON);
 JSONArray arrayJSON = myjson.getJSONArray("Results");
```

Ahora realizamos lo siguiente

```
int tamanhioArray = arrayJSON.length();
ArrayList<JSONObject> listResults = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < tamanhioArray; i++) {
    JSONObject otroObject = listResults.getJSONObject(i);

    listResults.add(otroObject);
}

JSONObject[] jsonsFinally= new JSONObject[listResults.size()];
listResults.toArray(jsonFinally);
```

Comment: Disculpa JSONObject y JSONArray, de que librerias son? Netbeans no me los esta encontrando para importarlos

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/json-lib/ Toma ! JSON Library

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una clase que llamaremos Order así:

```
class Order {

 @SerializedName("order_id")
 private String order_id;
 @SerializedName("paging")
 private Map<String, int> paging;
 @SerializedName("results")
 private List<Item> results;

}
```

Entonces tu puedes usar GSON para convertir el JSON a un objeto Order directamente

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Order order = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, Order.class);
```

Después simplemente accede a `order.getResults()` y ya tendrías el array.

Mira a ver si tu problema es que no has usado el `@SerializedName` o que en la clase Item falten también.